# Adding max_retries and retry_on_timeout to Elastic request (Python)

Tags: elasticsearch, request, timeout

I want to post a request to Elastic API via request module:

```
headers = {'Accept': "application/json", 'Content-type': "application/json"}
respond = requests.post(url=ES_CLIENT + "/" + index_name + "/_bulk", auth=auth, headers=headers, data=data_to_post)
```

To avoid a timeout I was wondering how to add "max_retries" and "retry_on_timeout" to this request.

Anyone might help here? Or is using Python Elasticsearch Client the only possible way to handle this?

Best
Äx

Answer (score 0):

Most ES clients (Python, Ruby, Java) just wrap Standard REST API calls. You can even make a CURL request as long as you specify whatever you need in the headers/body.
There is no compulsion to use any client. You can get away with this with any HTTP client. It just reduces the amount of code you need to write.
Bulk api calls should be kept to a certain maximum size and chopped when the size is exceeded. Clients usually have inbuilt support for such operations.
HTH.